# How to convert object to float in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I read a csv file into a pandas dataframe and got all column types as objects. I need to convert the second and third columns to float.

I tried using

```
df["Quantidade"] = pd.to_numeric(df.Quantidade, errors='coerce')
```

but got NaN.

Here's my dataframe. Should I need to use some regex in the third column to get rid of the "R$ "?

[image]

Comment: You have to change `,` to `.` and then convert

Comment: Quick question: in the third column, what are the numbers you're looking for? 16500000 or 165000 or 165?

Comment: Take the fifth value for example. I need them to be 49 thousand, 375 and 72 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# sample dataframe
d = {'Quantidade':['0,20939', '0,0082525', '0,009852', '0,012920', '0,0252'],
     'price':['R$ 165.000,00', 'R$ 100.000,00', 'R$ 61.500,00', 'R$ 65.900,00', 'R$ 49.375,12']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
# Second column
df["Quantidade"] = df["Quantidade"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)

#Third column
df['price'] = df.price.str.replace(r'\w+\$\s+', '').str.replace('.', '')\
                   .str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Output:

```
Quantidade  price
0   0.209390    165000.00
1   0.008252    100000.00
2   0.009852    61500.00
3   0.012920    65900.00
4   0.025200    49375.12
```

Comment: I edited the answer, now it's easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
df["Quantidade"] = df["Quantidade"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Comment: That worked. For the third column, I applied the same strategy. I got rid of "R", then $. Do I need to have 165.000,00 or 165.000.00 ? Both are not converting to float.

Answer (score 0):

df['Quantidade'] = df['Quantidade'].astype(float)